# Dot product and determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, cross-product

Why is it true that
$$
(\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}) \cdot \mathbf{u} =
        \begin{array}{|rrr|}
             u_1&u_2&u_3\\
             u_1&u_2&u_3\\
             v_1&v2&v3
        \end{array}
$$? That is, the dot product of the cross product between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ with $\mathbf{u}$ is equal to the above determinant. Why is that true?

I know that you can see the cross product as the determinant:
$$
        \begin{array}{|rrr|}
             \mathbf{i}&\mathbf{j}&\mathbf{k}\\
             u_1&u_2&u_3\\
             v_1&v2&v3
        \end{array}
$$
but still I cannot see how the above is true.

Comment: Note that your dot product is $0$ (because $\mathbf u\times\mathbf v\perp\mathbf u)$ and your determinant is $0$ (because two rows are the same)

Answer (score 2):

The [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Computing_the_cross_product) $\mathbf u\times \mathbf v$ is $(u_2v_3-u_3v_2)\mathbf i+(u_3v_1-u_1v_3)\mathbf j+(u_1v_2-u_2v_1)\mathbf  k$,

so $(\mathbf u\times \mathbf v )\cdot \mathbf u=(u_2v_3-u_3v_2)u_1+(u_3v_1-u_1v_3)u_2+(u_1v_2-u_2v_1)u_3,$

and the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is $u_1u_2v_3+u_2u_3v_1+u_3u_1v_2-u_3u_2v_1-u_2u_1v_3-u_1u_3v_2$,

so they're the same.